# Подсветка части текста внутри html тега

Tags: html, строки, highlighting

Как лучше реализовать подсветку букв внутри тега, при посимвольном совпадении с вводимый в input текстом ? При том что нужно чтобы теги и классы не пострадали. При ввроде текста в поле input совпадающие с ним буквы из списка должны окрашиваться в другой цвет

```js
const inputText = document.querySelector('#text'),
            searchListItems = document.querySelectorAll('#search-list a');

inputText.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    searchListItems.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.textContent.indexOf(inputText.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        console.log('coincidence')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.file{display:block;position:relative;padding:0 0 0 10px}
.file::before{content:'';display:block;width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;top:50%;left:-20px;transform:translate(0,-50%)}
.file.text::before{background:coral}
.file.video::before{background:steelblue}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">

<ul id="search-list">
  <li><a href="#" class="file text">point 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="file text">pointer 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="file video">points 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="file video">point 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="file video">point 5</a></li>
</ul>
```